# angular animations [@.disabled] freeze the page

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I want to disable angular animation by condition.
I looked in the docs and i seen the @.disabled property.
when I add the property the app is freeze.
when I remove it its working as expected.
how can I fix this?

I added example. if you will remove the disabled the app will work (without css) but with the property the page stuck.

[this is the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-ng-if-kgxeje?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: While the `@.disabled` directive will disable child animations, it will still run the animation callbacks (`start`/`done`). In the provided Stackblitz example, the `done` callback runs and resets the `messages` array. This causes the animations and their callbacks to run again, creating an infinite loop and freezing up the browser.

Comment: thanks, so how can i make the animations to not trigger if the messages ===1?

Comment: You should be able to bind the expression to the directive's input

`[@.disabled]="messages === 1"`